# update a portion of array in graphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, graphql-js

So I've decided to use graphql as my query engine along side with mongodb. So I created my schemas and everything looks great, BUT, one of my schemas contains a list of Strings, for instance:

```
exports.default = new gql.GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'myModel',
    fields: {
        type: { type: gql.GraphQLString },
        workingDays: { type: new gql.GraphQLList(GraphQLString) }
    }
});
```

So in the workingDays list I have 50 elements, and I'd like to change one of them, is there a way to do that with Graphql?

It just so happens to be a string type inside but, it could be an object as well.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean some data maybe a string or object

Comment: you can come up with your own API that allows this possibility, like an `updateWorkingDays(modelId: ID!, index: Int!, workDay: String)` mutation.

Comment: If you define `workingDays` as a list of strings, then you need to stick with that schema, you can't send 49 strings and 1 object. You could add another attribute to the `myModel` type like `workingDaysObjects`, which would be not required array of objects, where you would put those extra objects (if i understand your question correctly).

Comment: @marktani okay, that seems like this is the solution. can you please write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new mutation that encodes this functionality.

For example `updateWorkingDays(modelId: ID!, index: Int!, workDay: String)` that updates the working day of model `modelId` at `index` to the new `workDay`.